# jQuery click never called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox_square">
    <input id="check_profile_password_show" type="checkbox" value=""></input>
    <label for="check_profile_password_show"></label>
    <span class="span-small" th:text="#{label.password_show}"></span>
</div>
```

And if you click on that checkbox i want to change the input type of my password inputs:

```
/**
 * 
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("ready");

    /**
     * 
     */
    $("#check_profile_password_show").click(function() {
        alert("click");

        if ($("#profile_password_input").attr("type") == "password") {
            $("#profile_password_input").attr("type", "text");
        } else {
            $("#profile_password_input").attr("type", "password");
        }

        if ($("#profile_password_input_new").attr("type") == "password") {
            $("#profile_password_input_new").attr("type", "text");
        } else {
            $("#profile_password_input_new").attr("type", "password");
        }

        if ($("#profile_password_input_repeat").attr("type") == "password") {
            $("#profile_password_input_repeat").attr("type", "text");
        } else {
            $("#profile_password_input_repeat").attr("type", "password");
        }
    });
});
```

the "ready" alert is called but the click alert is never called, so the click function of my input checkbox is not overriden. I included the correct javascript file (ready alert works) and i also have a similiar mechanik in another javascript file:

```
/**
 * 
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    /**
     * 
     */
    $("#check_login_password_show").click(function() {
        if ($("#login_password_input").attr("type") == "password") {
            $("#login_password_input").attr("type", "text");
        } else {
            $("#login_password_input").attr("type", "password");
        }
    });
});
```

Which is working perfectly.
So it is the same code. One is working - one not. Can you help me figuring out what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe if you use `change` instead of click?

Comment: Are you sure your IDs are unique? Create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: on clicking checkbox , it gives alert correctly - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vKgxWQ

Comment: what could be the error then, if the code is working?

Comment: are you seeing any error in console.log??

Comment: no. no error at all.

Comment: Either the element is not in the DOM at the time you register the even handler, then the solution of PootieTang is correct, if you have multiple elements with the same `id` then it is a work around but not the correct solution. To check this you should change `alert("ready");` to `alert("ready: "+$("[id='check_profile_password_show']").length)`, if it is `0` then it was not in the DOM, if it is lager then `1`  then you should fixed the issue of having duplicate ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target element doesn't exist when the click handler is created then it won't work like that.

Another way to get it to work is to target the document instead.

```
$(document).on("click", "#check_profile_password_show", function(){
    alert("poop");
});
```

Comment: yes. with that it is working. dont know why my other codes are working then. thank you.

Comment: it just depends what's in the dom when you call click. when you do it this way it doesn't matter what's in the dom it will listen for the click when the item is added. since this fixed the problem, please hit the checkmark :) good luck

Comment: If the OP has duplicate ids in the DOM, then your solution can work, but could also fail, because multiple ids are invalid and could be corrected by the browser. So @Mulgard should check that before using your solution.

Comment: I dont have multiple id's. I checked that by replacing the ID with something random and it still did not work.